# force password change every 6 months in Plone

Tags: plone, change-password

Is there a way to force all the users to change their password once every six months?. I am using Plone 4.2 on a linux box.This is primarily for security purposes. Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting point for a PAS plugin would be Products.LoginLockout. It intercepts already the authentication process and deals with aspects like password-entered-N-times-wrong. In addition it stores already information about login time etc...it should not be so hard to extend.

Answer (score 3):

There is no already-existing add-on  that does this, but you could write one yourself.  Core documentation for Plone's "Pluggable Authentication Service" is at http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/members/pluggable_authentication_service/index.html.